# Correctly type dynamic array items according to array element's attribute value

Tags: typescript, dynamic-arrays

Say I have an array like so:

```json
[
    { id: 1, component: "mockup", src: "some-link" },
    { id: 2, component: "header", title: "Some Title", subtitle: "Lorem ipsum..." }
]
```

I am supposed to render according to the component key's value. How can I tell typescript to expect additional attributes if the `component` attribute equals to *this* or not expect this attribute if the component value equals to *that*? Is this beyond the scope of Typescript?

Comment: In my opinion you're better off changing your data structure so that your the differences between array items are contained within an object. e.g. {id: 1, component: "mockup", data: { ... } }. I know this doesn't address your problem but you'll find it much easier to type things this way rather than having an array of different types.

Comment: @Alex This data structure actually comes from Strapi's API in regards to their dynamic zones so I am not really in a place to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
interface Base {
  id: number;
  component: string;
}

interface MockupComponent extends Base {
  component: 'mockup';
  src: string;
}

interface HeaderComponent extends Base {
  component: 'header',
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
}

type Component = MockupComponent | HeaderComponent;

const components: Component[] = [
    { id: 1, component: "mockup", src: "some-link" },
    { id: 2, component: "header", title: "Some Title", subtitle: "Lorem ipsum..." },
    { id: 3, component: "other"}, // error
    { id: 3, component: "header", src: "some-link"}, // error
];
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7IID2VADiyBOGRmFFABzRgF9cuUJFiIUAWRYIA1hXYBhNp27hkEAB6QQRDGkw4mrDlx5gyAciqKV7O4wIYoCPgOFiJU6HgkZAAJCDgiaA0rbTBdAx5jUyxkPAJLLRt7AAtwyKg7ABomMGAwABsIb0EQESYMChpSiqrkfhq68VwwAE92FGjMnQBeZAVlVUHrHQAfULyozWmwRlxWEH5mJdiMMinYgG0AXWRRg6YCbEJSZABGQq2YrOQAIkcJ9heHjy9XjDYIABacqgJQvZCiYoES7XMgAJgeGWWZBeuQi0C+yGalRRAGUAcgACplSqYhpNEmtF4AGRYUAgVEI7AaVAAdOzwZCLqlYcgAMyI7bPF4sMC5KAvSHIAD00t0UCgdO5V2IZAFjyGtleaPyZM8KP+VCBIJAYKlsvliqguCOQA)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a map containing every component type's required attributes (as if you were creating an interface) like so :

```
const componentNameToAttributesMap = new Map<string, string[]([
    ["mockup", ['id', 'component', 'src']],
    ["header", ['id', 'component', 'title', 'subtitle']] 
]);
```

During rendering, you can then look up for the current component's name to fetch its attributes :

```
renderComponent(componentObj) {
   if (!componentNameToAttributesMap.has(componentObj.component)) {
       throw new Error(`Unknown component ${componentObj.component}`)
   }
   
   // then we check if component has every required attribute :

   componentNameToAttributesMap.get(componentObj.component)
   .forEach(attr => {
       if (!componentObj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
           throw new Error(`Component ${componentObj.component} is supposed to have attribute ${attr}`)
       }
   }
   // then you can put your render logic here
}
```

Cheers